# Using qsort with an array of strucs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, qsort

When I try to use qsort to sort an array of structs, I get this error: qsort cannot convert from int to __compar_fn_t.

the source code is:

```
struct idpar_exchange
{
int idp;
long long int exchange_d;

};

int ptg_partitioning::compare_by_data(const void* a, const void* b)
{
struct idpar_exchange *ia= (struct idpar_exchange *)a;
struct idpar_exchange *ib= (struct idpar_exchange *)b;
return ia->exchange_d - ib->exchange_d;
}


struct idpar_exchange v[list_part.size()][list_part.size()];

qsort(v[i],(sizeof(v[i])/(sizeof(struct idpar_exchange))),sizeof(struct idpar_exchange),compare_by_data);
```

Comment: Your code says `compare_by_data` is a function, the error message says it's an `int`. What gives? Did you write `compare_by_data()` when calling `qsort`?

Comment: @chill Don't arbitrarily change tags. This is not C code as it has a member function. And even if it didn't have C++-only features, you should not change the tag because there are some differences between the languages.

Comment: @nos For all we know, `ptg_partitioning` could be a namespace. @OP, we need a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @nos No `extern "C"` needed when calling `std::qsort`. That said, @OP, don’t use `qsort`. Use `std::sort`, and remove all those pesky C features from your C++ code.

Comment: just make compare_by_data static, problem solved.

Comment: Why you are using `qsort()` instead of `std::sort()`? Do you know `std::sort()` is nearly two times faster than `qsort()` due to inlining and no `void*` pointers? And is much more easier to use than `qsort` by far.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/P45mGH) is a comparison about the performance of `std::sort()` vs `qsort()`. Its pretty clear. Why that difference?: `qsort()` takes a function pointer as comparer, i.e. the compiler cannot inline it. Also `qsort()` uses `void*` parameters on the comparer. That leads to runtime conversions which can affect performance.